# Outlook: How to auto accept meeting tentatively if there is another tentative meeting booked

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation, calendar

So I have too many meetings (like everyone else) and some I attend if I have time and they're booked as "tentative".

I've also turned on auto-accept and decline of meetings (one of the reasons why I have too many meetings) but I'd like Outlook to accept meetings tentatively *when there is another tentative meeting in the same spot*  (it now just rejects the meeting)

I tried googling and rummaging through the Registry but didn't find much, so turning to a sister site of my main site for help... **:-)**

P.S. Running Outlook 2013, but if a solution exists for a more recent version, I'll wait for the new version to be deployed...

Comment: This might not apply to your Outlook version : In File / Options / Calendar / Auto accept or decline, do you have checked "Automatically decline meeting requests that conflict with an existing appointment or meeting"?

Comment: I see 3 choices: Automatically accept meeting requests and remove cancelled meetings /
Automatically decline meeting requests that conflict with an existing appointment or meeting / Automatically decline recurring meeting events. Which version are you running? @harrymc

Comment: Is your 2nd option unchecked?

Comment: Nope, checked...  @harrymc

Comment: So better uncheck it.

Comment: Yeah, then it auto-accepts, *permanently not tentatively*.

Comment: This option is about *declining* and is probably what causes your problem. I don't see its connection with *acceptance*.

Answer (score 3):

Use this procedure :

- Open Outlook, and then click the **File** tab.
- Click **Options** and then **Calendar** in the left sidebar.
- Click the **Auto-Accept, Decline** button in the **Automatic Accept or Decline** section.
- You have already marked as checked the option of **Automatically Accept Meeting Requests and Remove Canceled Meetings**, so leave it this way.
- Mark as unchecked the option of
  **Automatically Decline Meeting Requests That Conflict With an Existing Appointment or Meeting**, which you currently have as checked.
- Click **OK** twice to save the settings and close the dialog box.

[image]

---

It seems that the poster is up against a bug in Outlook 2013, where
following the above advice causes the meetings to be accepted
permanently and not tentatively. Updating to Outlook 2016 might fix
this problem, or might not (I can't test as I'm not using Outlook).

In such a case one might need to resort to a VBA macro.
Below is one possibility :

```
Sub AutoAcceptMeetings(oRequest As MeetingItem)

If oRequest.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)

Dim oResponse
 Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingTentative, True)
 oResponse.Display '.Send
End Sub
```

To use the above macro, open Outlook's VBA editor (Alt+F11),
expand `Microsoft Office Outlook Objects`, then double-click on
`ThisOutlookSession`. Type or paste the above code into the module,
then create the rule with the `run script` Action and select this script.

As I'm not using Outlook, you might need to experiment with the above
until you get it right.

References :

- [How to use Outlook's VBA Editor](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/)
- [Outlook VBA reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-outlook)
- [Autoaccept a Meeting Request using Rules](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/autoaccept-a-meeting-request-using-rules/)
- [Outlook Respond Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210273(v=office.11).aspx)
- [Outlook rule to auto accept / decline meetings](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_republic/2011/12/09/outlook-rule-to-auto-accept-or-auto-decline-meeting-invites/)

Comment: As per comments below the question:  That doesn't work: it accepts the meeting *permanently, **not tentatively***

Comment: It's still unclear to me how this option could have an effect on acceptance, as it's only about declining. If it does affect acceptance, this can only be an  Outlook bug. But there is no other option, as far as I know, that can solve your problem.

Comment: That's why I posted the question here: normally I solve my own problems, but now I'm stumped...  **;-)**

Comment: Microsoft can have that effect on us mere mortals. You might submit a bug report via File / Feedback / Send a frown. Or you might post on `https://answers.microsoft.com/`, where Microsoft employees or MVPs may answer, some of whom may have connections to the developers. Or your company may have a support contract with Microsoft such as the MSDN.

Comment: I added to my answer the possibility of using a VBA macro to override the buggy behavior of Outlook. Not using Outlook, I cannot vouch for the above macro, but added many references which will get you started.